# Boxplots and conditional statements in R

Tags: r

How can I write the following in correct R syntax?

```r
boxplot(myCsvData$time **WHERE/IF** condition == "baseline")
```

Im struggling with the `if` condition. Thanks a lot for any answers!

Comment: Welcome. You need to explain what you are trying to do before anyone can help you. Please also include a reproducible example of your issue - take a moment to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, what you want is:

```
boxplot(myCsvData$time[myCsvData$condition == "baseline"])
```